# Most efficient to search a javascript object or an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of JavaScript objects

```
var arrayObjs = [
{ id:abc123, radius:5.0},
{ id:def235, radius:2.5},...]
```

I have been using a for loop to find a particular object with id = def235, would it be more efficient to use an object like

```
var objectObjs = {
{ abc123:{ id:abc123, radius:5.0}},
{ def235:{ id:def235, radius:2.5}},...}
```

Comment: Why don't you just test and measure ? Most of performance work is just measuring for your cases.

Answer (score 1):

> would it be more efficient to use an object like

If you're looking up by `id`, yes, almost certainly, but your example has an extra layer of `{}` you'll want to remove:

```
var objectObjs = {
    abc123:{ id:abc123, radius:5.0},
    def235:{ id:def235, radius:2.5},
    //...
};
```

JavaScript objects are highly-optimized for property retrieval by name.

Another option is to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is also optimized for retrieval by key.

If you use an object, probably best to create it via [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) so it doesn't inherit `Object.prototype` properties. You probably aren't going to look up `id`s like `toString` or `valueOf`, but still... :-) So perhaps:

```
var objectObjs = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    abc123:{ id:abc123, radius:5.0},
    def235:{ id:def235, radius:2.5},
    //...
});
```

It's also trivial to create that object from your array, to avoid typing the `id`s twice and the opportunity for error that introduces:

```
var arrayObjs = [
{ id:abc123, radius:5.0},
{ id:def235, radius:2.5},/*...*/];
var objectObjs = Object.create(null);
arrayObjs.forEach(entry => { objectObjs[entry.id] = entry; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I tried it: https://jsperf.com/accessor-test-loop-vs-object

Of course, as T.J. described - access by an object property is much faster. Interestingly, on `Chrome` the difference is much greater than on `Firefox` as I just tried out. Try to run the test of Chrome and Firefox or Edge.

```
var arrayObjs = [
  { id:'abc123', radius:5.0},
  { id:'def235', radius:2.5}
];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayObjs.length; i++) {
  if (arrayObjs[i].id == 'def235') {
    // found it
    break;
  }
}
```

..VS..

```
var objectObjs = {
  abc123:{ id: 'abc123', radius: 5.0},
  def235:{ id: 'def235', radius: 2.5}
}

var found = !!objectObjs.def235;
if (found) {
  // ..
}
```